# Submitting the sitemaps in Google WMT

Tags: seo

Will it hamper my site if I resubmit the sitemaps to Google WMT again and again at frequent intervals during a month?

I work on various pages of a website from an SEO and designer point of view and make changes to the as an when the client wants in addition to the work I do. I wanted to know if submitting the sitemap for my website to Google WMT every week will hamper the Google bots crawling my website or will it be fine?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the WMT sitemap submission tool.

Once you submit the location of your sitemap, you don't need to resubmit it again unless you are changing the location/name of the sitemap file. You just update the sitemap at the location and it will be processed on regular intervals by google.

You can also see the last processed date on google webmasters tool (now search console).

Answer (score -1):

If you have changes on your sitemap there is no problem to resubmitted as often as it is needed. Also you can speed up how often google bot come on your site "craw rate".

[https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/09/change-googlebot-crawl-rate.html)

Comment: As per google - Crawl rate refers to the speed of Googlebot's requests during the crawl process. It doesn't have any effect on how often we crawl or how deeply we crawl your URL structure.

Comment: But isn't it if the speed is faster and google can craw them faster, this will take effect on how often the site is recrawed ?

Comment: That's what I am confused about too franksow and aakash. I wondered that if I submit the website after I change a dozen pages, that will help the search engines know about the change and they will crawl the website. Isnt that true?